# pt-table-checksum show wrong DIFF

Tags: mysql, percona, pt-table-checksum

I'm try to use pt-table-checksum tool. I have Master/Slave tables, and I add some rows to the slave to check it.

```
pt-table-checksum --ignore-databases mysql S=/tmp/5.6.22_3306_Master/data/mysql.sock --user=SlaveUser --password=1234
```

produce this result:

```
            TS ERRORS  DIFFS     ROWS  CHUNKS SKIPPED    TIME TABLE
07-21T16:47:35      0      0        8       1       0   0.008 test.Countries
07-21T16:47:35      0      0        0       1       0   0.006 test.Persons
```

When I run this query (`SELECT * FROM percona.checksums WHERE db not like 'mysql';`) on the **slave** I can see the difference:

[image]

How I can see the right result and the diff with pt-table-checksum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Manual states it clearly:

> If you wish, you can query the checksum tables manually to get a
>   report of which tables and chunks have differences from the master.
>   The following query will report every database and table with
>   differences, along with a summary of the number of chunks and rows
>   possibly affected:
>
> ```
> SELECT db, tbl, SUM(this_cnt) AS total_rows, COUNT(*) AS chunks
> FROM percona.checksums
> WHERE (
>  master_cnt <> this_cnt
>  OR master_crc <> this_crc
>  OR ISNULL(master_crc) <> ISNULL(this_crc))
> GROUP BY db, tbl;
> ```
>
> The table referenced in that query is the checksum table, where the
>   checksums are stored. Each row in the table contains the checksum of
>   one chunk of data from some table in the server.

To get the actual differences, you'd need to run `pt-table-sync --print` and determine the changes by the SQL queries it generates.

Comment: I saw on the manual. But yet, shouldn't I see difference on the output table?

Comment: yes but with the above query you'll get the summary of chunks and estimated rows affected.